# Reading a .scss file with fetch api

Tags: javascript, sass, fetch-api

I'm trying to get a .scss file, that has variables declared in it, that's inside my public folder and read the text inside of it.

here's what I tried:

```
fetch('someFolder/someFolder/_variables.scss')
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

which returns undefined. This is my first time using the fetch api, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think param should be an url.

Comment: are you talking about what's passed to fetch? because that is a url

Comment: You are passing an url or path?

Comment: i think it should work if you try something like this fetch("http://localhost:3000/somefolder/file.scss")

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: nope still doesn't work.

Comment: @Amy 200. it returns the file, and i can see it in the network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response of `fetch` is a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. Since it does not have a property named `data`, the result is indeed undefined. The following should work:

```
fetch('someFolder/someFolder/_variables.scss')
  .then(response => response.text()) // <----
  .then(response => console.log(response))
```

See [response.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).

Comment: Your answer is 90% correct. it should be ```response``` in the last part instead of ```response.data```

Comment: @ShayanJavadi indeed, since it is just text and not json. Changed it. Glad I could help.